# How delete "NULL" from Sql

Tags: sql

I have NULL values in my table.

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Mark]
      ,[Series]
      ,[Models]
      ,[Power]
  FROM [ExcelAnalysis].[dbo].[Dict]
```

Here the screen
[http://imgur.com/a/kAOYA](https://imgur.com/a/kAOYA)

so i try do so

```
update tablename 
set fieldname = REPLACE ( fieldname , string_pattern , string_replacement )


update [dbo].[Dict]
set [Mark] = REPLACE ( [Mark] , 'NULL' , '' )
```

but after executing the query, NULL values i see again

How correct delete it?

Comment: You don't seem to know what `null` is. And why would you want to replace it with an empty string?

Comment: `NULL` is not a value. It represents the absence of a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with `NULL` (*null value*, please, notice absence of the apostrophs), not `'NULL'` (*string* `NULL`)

```
 update [dbo].[Dict]
    set [Mark] = ''
  where [Mark] is null
```

Comment: Thanks you)  i understood ,the null is not string)

Comment: so , Dmitry, how do this replace for all field at once  select *  :)

Comment: @D.Joe: Sorry, I don't follow you? If you want "if field is null substitute it with `''` " construction, try `Coalesce(field, '')`. `Coalesce` returns *1st not null value*

Comment: i mean replace NULL in all table at once))

Comment: @D.Joe: the query in the answer replaces all `null` values in the `[Mark]` fields for the *entire* `[dbo].[Dict]` table

Answer (score 1):

For `NULL` use `COALESCE()` or a `WHERE` clause:

```
update [dbo].[Dict]
    set [Mark] = ''
    where [Mark] is null;
```

`NULL` is not a string value.

Comment: Probably would be better to not just replace NULL with an emtpy string but explain what NULL is.